# WPF MVVM C# Opening a PDF document with tool pane hidden by default

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, mvvm, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF WebBrowser where I open a pdf file:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="browser" HtmlText="{Binding PdfFile}"/>
```

View Model:

```
public string PdfFile
{
   get
   {
      string file = GetPdfFile();

      return string.Format("{0}#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=1&view=FitV", file);
   }
}
```

I would like to open this PDF with the right vertical toolbar panel hidden (collapsed) by default. Now it opens the pdf and toolbar panel is visible (expanded).

By tool panel, I refer to that where appear the options (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC): "Export pdf file", "Create Pdf file", "Edit Pdf", and so on.

As you can see I pass as parameter "toolbar=1". With it I open the toolbar at the top of the document. Left vertical tool bar panel is shown hidden (collapsed) by default but right vertical toolbar panel is shown visible (expanded) by default. I want it to be hidden by default as the left vertical tool bar panel.

Comment: Have you tried these options when opening the PDF via command line? E.G. you first have to be sure it will work outside of the web browser control before you can be sure it will work inside the web browser control.

Comment: It sounds like you already read their reference at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf